# How to bind bindable object to the xml file in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have created custom bordered stacklayout for android using custom renderer. 
The StackLayout border is created by using xml file. The border color is defined in that xml file. But I want to change that border color dynamically at runtime using bindable object property. I have done this with ios. But i dont have any idea how to bind the bindable object to the xml file. My customBorderStacklayout sample code is mentioned below, Please share your valuable suggestion to done this.

**CustomStackBorder.cs**

```
public class CustomStackBorder : StackLayout
{
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("BorderColor", typeof(Color), typeof(CustomStackBorder), Color.Gray, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public CustomStackBorder()
    {       
    }
}
```

**CustomStackLayoutRenderer.cs** (Android)

```
public class CustomStackLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
{
      public CustomStackLayoutRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
      {
      }
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
      {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, Resource.Drawable.StackLayoutBorder);            
      }
}
```

**StackLayoutBorder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="#ff555555"></stroke>
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:topRightRadius="2dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" />
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the **stroke color** of the drawable.

**Code:**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (e.NewElement as CustomStackBorder != null)
            {
                Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, Resource.Drawable.StackLayoutBorder);
                GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)this.Background;
                bgShape.SetStroke(1, (e.NewElement as CustomStackBorder).BorderColor.ToAndroid());

            }
        }
    }
```

Change your **OnElementChanged** method in custom stack view renderer with my code and replace your `BorderColor` property value with real data. That is all you have to do.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I have tried your code but it will return the following exception, **Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color**

Comment: @Yogeshwaran, I have updated my code. Please have a look.